# Linux Apache web server : Unable to access from windows mchine

Tags: linux, apache

I have installed Apache web server on Redhat Linux and able to access the web server locally from Linux. EIther using http://loclahost/ or http://ip.address/

But same if i tried from windows machine using intranet then unable to access the web server. I am able to ping the Linux machine from windows since both are in intranet.

Please share if any information or how to fixed same.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your http port (80) on linux might not be open for outside incoming request...

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-iptables-firewall-open-port-80/

Comment: Great help and million of thank you. This works. Many Many thanks for sharing the information indeed it is great site on earth ...

Comment: If this worked, you should mark the answer as 'accepted'. It is the tick icon on left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a firewall issue. If your server is protected inside your intranet, you might try switching off the firewall on your linux box temporarily to see if that fixes it.

One way to test if server ports are accessible is to use telnet to connect to them:

```
$ telnet ip.or.name.of.host 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure apache is using port 80 and then tell What is the output of "telnet <ip> 80" from the windows machine (might to have to install telnet through control center first). If you don't get a connection, maybe it is blocked by a firewall? Or you have another program running on your linux machine that is using port 80 (ie skype), but then you wouldn't be able to open the webpage from linux either.